# javascript get array value by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I have an array

```
var hex_to_dec = {
    '0' : 0,
    '1' : 1,
    '2' : 2,
    '3' : 3,
    '4' : 4,
    '5' : 5,
    '6' : 6,
    '7' : 7,
    '8' : 8,
    '9' : 9,
    'A' : 10,
    'B' : 11,
    'c' : 12,
    'D' : 13,
    'E' : 14,
    'F' : 15
};
```

and a function

```
function get_dec_from_hex(key){//if key=A
    console.log(hex_to_dec["A"]);//works
    return hex_to_dec[key];//doesnt work
}
```

i am trying to get the value when the key is a letter and it doesnt work... but when the key is a number i can get the value without getting "undefined" output

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dncgP/. Make sure `key` contains the right value.

Comment: console.log("value is: "+ get_dec_from_hex("B")); works fine for me also.

Comment: yes it works fine when i have the "" in place... if you simply translate the call of the object hex_to_dec[key] where key=A it wont work

Comment: Of course, `hex_to_dec[A]` is different than `hex_to_dec["A"]`. In the first case, `A` is a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to maintain that list of conversion's yourself, `parseInt` will get you there easier.

try this in your console:

```
parseInt('1', 16) // 1
parseInt('2', 16) // 2
...
parseInt('A', 16) // 10
parseInt('B', 16) // 11
...
parseInt('F', 16) // 15
```

---

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> Parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix
>   or base.
>
> `var intValue = parseInt(string[, radix]);`
>
> **string**
>
> The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to
>   one. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored.
>
> **radix**
>
> An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. While this
>   parameter is optional, always specify it to eliminate reader confusion
>   and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations
>   produce different results when a radix is not specified.

Comment: yeah... the bad thing is that i have used this function like 10 times below that bunch of code i am writing atm... i am so tired... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First, `hex_to_dec` is not an array, is an object.
And your function works fine, try:

```
function get_dec_from_hex(key){
    return hex_to_dec[key];
} 

console.log(get_dec_from_hex("D"));
```

Comment: as an amendment to this answer,  make sure you are passing a string value, i.e. "A" and not an unknown reference, i.e. A